# How can I make link go to a page and toggle popup in it?

Tags: hyperlink, popup, toggle, html-email

I need to have a link open certain page and toggle a hidden popup in it right after. The popup normally shows by click on a specified button on that page. Is this even possible? I need this for a html email template, so not sure if javascript will work

Comment: Email development is NOT front-end development. JavaScript will not work in most email clients. If you can do it in css, it's possible. Just because I can't think of a way to make this work is not important. If you can think of a way, do it.

Comment: Martin, the answer given below will only work when the email is viewed online. As @gwally said will not work in most email clients don't support JavaScript in emails. The answer you have chosen will not work.

Comment: It works on mobile but only if the user open the link in mobile browser not through the email client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would append a URL parameter to the link in the email... Something like 
`?popup=true`

Then, on the page that you've linked to in JavaScript you can check for that URL parameter then display the popup.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (urlParams.get('popup') === 'true') {
    // show popup code here... $('.popup').show() if using jQuery...
}
```

URLSearchParams doesn't working in IE though https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

So if you need to support IE you can use this function instead

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

Comment: That's right, but he means to add the JS to the page, not in the email. You just add some parameter to the URL which is possible in the html. This actually works.

Comment: The only time the JS will work is when the email is viewed online. Also the page is the email?

Comment: No. I have a html email where is the link www.example.com/contact-us?popup=true . This link redirect to a web page that detects if the link has the parameter and then open the popup. No JS in the html email. I think it will work everywhere, I checked it only on browser, will test it right away through email client

Comment: Unfortunately, no.